# How to fetch a JSON object in React if it is an object, not an array using the map method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch-api, django-serializer

This is my Django API, I want to map the product in react, but it is an object it is not an array, and I'm not able to display the product.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6o9P.png)

I try to solve like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMrDa.png)

Comment: You seem to be missing the code you wanted to add. Please add it so we better understand what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.